# Display mysql data to a dynamic stock type highchart

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, highcharts

good day. so I'm making a line chart with highchart types of stocks with data from mysql and succeed. Then I tried to make a dynamic stock type highchart like this demo [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/), because in the end result my web will display line chart data dynamically with data from mysql. But I am confused how to display mysql data with a dynamic line chart like in a demo. Can anyone help me how to display mysql data to a dynamic stock type line chart? Thank you for the help.

The code below is an experiment I display mysql data to a stock type highchart but not dynamic

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery3.js"></script>
<script src="code/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="haha.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
$(function() {
 $.getJSON('haha.php', function (data) {
// Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Temperature'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'Temperature',
            data : data,
            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 3
            },
            shadow : true,
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
```

PHP :

```
include("connection.php");

$data = array();
$count = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY waktu ASC ") or die ("Connection error");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//echo "[" . $row['time'] . "," . $row['value']. "]"."," ;
  $newdate = strtotime($row['waktu']) * 1000; 
$data[] = array($newdate, (float)$row['temperature']);
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($koneksi);
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: can anyone help me ??

Comment: As you can see, on mentioned demo, there is the `chart.events.load` function which adds a random data to the chart. You need to do it in the same way, but in every `setInterval` function, you need to ask for new `JSON` file for example. This JSON file should be generated and and always updated by your (or other) backend. Then you are just making `AJAX` call for it, that's all.